# Calculating direct sum of 2 binary numbers

Tags: arithmetic, binary

If we have say,key=‘0110‘ and =‘1100‘, how will ⊕key mod 2 be calculated and what will be the answer equal to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation $\oplus$ is the same as bitwise XOR. The same symbol is used for direct sum, but there is otherwise absolutely no relation.

Comment: Can this be also used when m has larger number of bits than key like m="101010" while key="101"? If so, how?

Comment: Yes. You pad the smaller one with zeroes.

Comment: I warmly recommend experimenting with the XOR operation in any programming language that supports it. This will answer all your questions.